# Woher kommt das Wort Zimtzicke?

Tags: etymology

Ich kenne das Wort *Zimtzicke* noch aus der Grundschule und bin neulich wieder darüber gestolpert.
Zunächst ging ich davon aus, es handle sich um reine Kindersprache, aber es steht im [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zimtzicke) (auch: *Zimtziege*) als Synonym für *Zicke*.

Als Erklärung der Herkunft des Wortes steht dort ein Verweis auf *Zimt*, was laut Duden »(umgangssprachlich abwertend) etwas, was für dumm, unsinnig, wertlos gehalten wird, was jemandem lästig o. ä. ist«.
Diese Bedeutung von Zimt war mir allerdings unbekannt.

Wie lässt sich diese Bedeutung erklären?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Die "Zimtzicke" hat nichts mit dem Gewürz "Zimt" zu tun. Im Rotwelschen (ein [Sammelbegriff für einige sondersprachliche Soziolekte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotwelsch)) stand "Zimt" früher für Geld oder Gold. Diese Bedeutung kehrte sich Anfang des 19. Jahrhunderts komplett um. Nun stand "Zimt" für Plunder oder wertloses Zeug. Die "Zimtzicke" ist also jemand, der wegen jedem Mist, wegen jeder Nichtigkeit herumzickt.

Quellen: [abendblatt.de](https://www.abendblatt.de/ratgeber/wissen/article108166519/Woher-stammt-der-Begriff-Zimtzicke.html), [pagewizz.com](https://pagewizz.com/was-ist-eine-zimtzicke-woher-stammt-der-begriff-28179/)

Comment: Ich wäre vorsichtig mit der Verwendung des Begriffs "das Rotwelsche". Was in der Literatur (insbesondere des 19. und frühen 20. Jahrhunderts als "Rotwelsch" bezeichnet wird, ist eigentlich eine Sammlung von Wörtern aus nicht-standardsprachlichen Ausdrucksformen verschiedenster (üblicherweise "bildungsferner") Bevölkerungsgruppen. Das alles zusammenzuwerfen zu einem "Rotwelschen" (oder einer "Gaunersprache") und damit zu behaupten, dieses bilde eine irgendwie geschlossene Einheit, scheint mir höchst fragwürdig.  Aber ich weiß, der Begriff geistert nach wie vor durch die Literatur.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Stimmt, das war zu sehr verkürzt, danke für den Hinweis. Ich habe eine Anmerkung zum Begriff "Rotwelsch" mit einem Link zum entsprechenden Wikipedia-Artikel eingebaut.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "Rotwelsch" ist ein durchaus gut etablierter Begriff, bei dem klar ist, dass es sich nicht um eine eigene Sprache sondern um Jargon handelt. Niemand behauptet, dass Rotwelsch eine "geschlossene Einheit" darstelle und man sollte den Begriff eigentlich auch nicht jedesmal neu erklären müssen. Ein Link zu Wikipedia kann allerdings auch nicht schaden.

Comment: Du schreibst: "Die "Zimtzicke" hat nichts mit dem Gewürz "Zimt" zu tun." Pfeifer sagt genau das Gegenteil. Die Etymologie von "Zimt" ist aber umstritten. https://www.dwds.de/wb/Zimt#1

Comment: @Takkat  Angesichts existierender Dinge wie "Wörterbuch des Rotwelschen" und so weiter halte ich den Hinweis, dass es "Rotwelsch" nicht eigentlich gibt, sondern dass es ein soziales Konstrukt (von Unbeteiligten) ist, schon für wichtig. Das ist nicht unähnlich der Orientalismus-Debatte. Dass der Begriff "etabliert" ist, ist hier nicht ein Qualitätsmerkmal sondern geradzu der Kern des Problems.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46700/was-ist-rotwelsch - da können wir all das hineinschreiben und den Begriff genau definieren. Bei der nächsten Erwähnung brauchen wir nur noch zu dieser Frage verlinken und alles ist gut.

Answer (score 6):

Eine andere Erklärungsmöglichkeit findet sich im Grimm'schen Wörterbuch unter dem Begriff [**zimtig**](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GZ06674#XGZ06674):

> obersächsische Mundartform im Sinne von zimperlich

Somit wäre es denkbar, dass sich aus einer "zimtigen Zicke" (also einer zimperlichen Person) die Zusammenziehung "Zimtzicke" entwickelt hat. Das ist aber nur eine Vermutung, für die ich keinen Beleg gefunden habe.