# Was ist Rotwelsch? What is "Rotwelsch"?

Tags: dialect, colloquial, slang

In Diskussionen zur einer [kürzlich gestellten Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46657/woher-kommt-das-wort-zimtzicke) wurde deutlich, dass ein Bedarf besteht, den Begriff genauer zu definieren.

Ist "Rotwelsch" ein Dialekt des Deutschen oder sogar eine eigene Sprache? Woher stammt der Begriff? Wird er heute noch benutzt, bzw. ist er ein anerkannter sprachwissenschaftlicher Terminus?

---

Discussions to a [recent question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46657/woher-kommt-das-wort-zimtzicke) revealed that we need a clear definition of this term.

Is "Rotwelsch" a German dialect or even an own language? Where did the term  originate? Is this term scientifically accepted still today?

Comment: Nur zur Rekapitulation und weil ich hier die Interessen von Stack Exchange vertrete: **wir sind selbst eine Art Internet-Lexikon zu Fragen über die deutsche Sprache**. Es hat schon seinen Grund, wenn wir Fragen, die man auch mit einem Lexikon beantworten kann, nicht unbedingt schließen wollen, denn die Leute sollen auch bei uns eine gute, wenn nicht sogar bessere Antwort finden.

Comment: Wäre die Antwort nicht nahezu eine Abschrift des entsprechenden [Wikipediaartikels](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotwelsch)?

Comment: @mtwde: wenn du unkreativ bist und nur eine Antwort per copy & paste schrieben kannst... vielleicht. Wikipedia ist toll, aber nicht der Weisheit letzter Schluss.

Comment: Ich würde die Frage gerne ergänzen: Inwiefern kann und soll man Parallelen ziehen zwischen einem "Rotwelschen" im deutschsprachigen Raum und der russischen Fäkalsprache "Mat"? (Erste Orientierung für Nichtslavisten siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russischer_Mat). - Es ist sicherlich nicht das gleiche, aber ich sehe interessante Überschneidungen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich hatte noch eine Idee für eine schöne Folgefrage, die du gerne stellen darfst: *Was wäre ein modernen Rotwelsch?* - Mir fällt dazu spontan die Sprache der Junkies,  Kanak-Sprak, Gossensprache als neuer Begriff, "Jugendsprache", etc. ein. Da würde vielleicht auch "Mat" passen.

Comment: @Takat   ... womit wir erneut bei der Frage wären: gibt es "*die* Jugendsprache", "*die* Junkie-Sprache", oder haben bestimmte Subgruppen ihre separierten Sprachkulturen? Oder ist mit der Einteilung in Jugend/Junkies/Kanak-Sprachler (v.a. wohl junge männliche Angehöriger aus dem sog. Orient kommender Bevölkerungsteile) schon eine realistische Abgrenzung getroffen?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Das meine ich gar nicht - mich interessiert, wie man "Rotwelsch" heute nennen würde, denn es ist ja ein historischer Begriff, so wie auch "Gaunersprache", die es ebenfalls heute nicht mehr gibt (oder doch?) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Meyers Konversationslexikon](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/schlagwort.html?wort=Rotwelsch) (Vierte Auflage, 1885-1892) schreibt:

> Rotwelsch (Rotwälsch), die älteste der vielen Bezeichnungen der Gaunersprache (s. Kochemer Loschen), kommt schon im Passional des 13. Jahrh. vor und wird abgeleitet von Rot (in der Gaunersprache s. v. w. Bettler, Landstreicher) und welsch (fremdartige Sprache).

Der Brockhaus (14. Auflage, 1894-1896) ist etwas ausführlicher und verweist auf unten aus dem Zitat extrahierten Quellen:

> Rotwelsch oder Rotwälsch (aus roter, soviel als Bettler, und wälsch, fremdartige Sprache), die Gauner- und Diebessprache Deutschlands. In Spanien heißt die Diebessprache Germania, in Frankreich Argot, in Italien Gergo, in England Cant, in Böhmen Hantyrka. In den skandinav. Ländern kommt als Fantesprog außer der Zigeuner-(Tatersproget) auch die Vagabundensprache (Sköiersproget) vor. Das R. heißt auch Jenische Sprache. Die unter den Gaunern selbst üblichen Ausdrücke für R. sind: Kochemer Loschen, Kaloschensprache, Kochemer Kohl, Chessenloschen u. a. In seinem lexikalischen Bestande geht das R. hauptsächlich auf das Jüdischdeutsche zurück, während es in seinen grammatischen Formen im wesentlichen deutsch ist. Es wurde in Deutschland schon zu den Zeiten Karls Ⅴ. besonders von den Gordenbrüdern (als Bettler herumstreichenden Soldaten) gesprochen, und man hat bereits von 1528 und vom nächsten Jahre darauf ein beidemal zu Wittenberg erschienenes Buch: «Von der falschen Betler bueberey, mit Vorrede von M. Luther. Und hinden an ein Rothwelsch Vocabularius.» Zur Zeit des Dreißigjährigen Krieges stand es in voller Blüte, wovon die «Gesichte Philanders von Sittewald» Zeugnis ablegen. Noch heute verdient das in seinem altüberlieferten Urstocke sich ziemlich gleichgebliebene R. die Aufmerksamkeit von Polizei- und Kriminalbehörden, und diesem praktischen Interesse hat man auch die besten Aufschlüsse zu danken.

- Pott,  Charakteristik der Gaunersprachen in dessen «Zigeunern» (Bd. 2, Einleitung, Halle 1845)
- Avé-Lallemant, Das deutsche Gaunertum (4 Bde., Lpz. 1858‒62)
- Anton, Wörterbuch der Gauner- und Diebessprache (3. Aufl., Berl. 1859)
- Wagner, Die Litteratur der Gauner- und Geheimsprachen (Dresd. 1861)
- Kahle, Die fahrenden Leute und ihre Sprache (Gera 1889)
- Biondelli, Studii sulle lingue furbesche (Mail. 1876)
- Michel, Étude de philologie comparée sur l’argot et sur les idiomes analogues parlés en Europe et en Asie (Par. 1856)
- Sundt, Beretning om Fanteeller Landstrygerfolket i Norge (2. Aufl., Krist. 1852)
- Dyrlund, Tatere og Natmandsfolk i Danmark (Kopenh. 1872)

Comment: Bei Zitaten aus Enzyklopädien ist es immer gut, man gibt das Erscheinungsjahr dazu an.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: über den Link erfährt man: Vierte Auflage, 1885-1892

Answer (score 6):

Hier folgt eine kritische Diskussion des Begriffs "Rotwelsch" beziehungsweise seiner unvorsichtigen Verwendung.

"Rotwelsch" wird in der (meist: sprachwissenschaflichen oder jedenfalls sprachbetrachterischen) Literatur des deutschsprachigen Raums traditionell (v.a. seit dem 19. Jahrhundert) als ein Begriff verwendet, um eine Reihe sprachlicher Ausdrucksformen (v.a. auf der lexikalischen Ebene) bestimmter (historischer) Bevölkerungsgruppen niedrigen sozialen Status' zu bezeichnen.

Der Begriff selbst ist seit der frühen Neuzeit dokumentiert (siehe Literaturliste unten mit einer Publikation von 1528).

In der Praxis geht es vor allem um die Sammlungen von Wörtern, die bestimmte Bevölkerungsgruppen abweichend vom standardsprachlichen Gebrauch verwendeten.

Der Begriff ist aus mehreren Gründen problematisch.

Erstens ist er eine Außenbezeichnung. Keiner jener Leute, die Ausdrucksformen benutzten, die andere (aus der sozial dominierenden Bildungsschicht) als "Rotwelsch" bezeichneten, wäre von sich aus auf den Gedanken gekommen zu sagen: "Ich spreche Rotwelsch."

Zweitens ist er eine Übergeneralisierung. Er wirft Dinge in einen Topf, die nicht in einen Topf gehören. Was in der Literatur (insbesondere des 19. und frühen 20. Jahrhunderts) als "Rotwelsch" bezeichnet wird, ist eigentlich eine Sammlung von Wörtern aus nicht-standardsprachlichen Ausdrucksformen verschiedenster (üblicherweise "bildungsferner") Bevölkerungsgruppen. Das alles zusammenzuwerfen zu einem "Rotwelschen" und damit zu behaupten, dieses bilde eine irgendwie geschlossene Einheit, führt in die Irre. Es wird eine sprachliche Entität behauptet, die außerhalb von Wörterbüchern und sprachbetrachterischen Traktaten gar nicht existiert(e).

Das verbindende Element zwischen den Soziolekten, auf die sich Sammlungen des "Rotwelschen" beziehen, ist der niedrige soziale Status oder Außenseiterstatus (man könnte auch Paria-Status sagen) der entsprechenden Träger dieser Sprachpraxen. Damit gerät man bei gedankenloser Verwendung des Begriffs "Rotwelsch" in die Gefahr, eine sozialen Ausgrenzung zu betreiben, in die sich schnell auch rassistische oder sonstwie diskriminatorische Motive mischen können.

Die Assoziation mit bestimmten, negativ gesehenen Bevölkerungsgruppen zeigt sich darin, dass in praktisch jeder Abhandlung über "Rotwelsch" zur Erklärung sogleich der Begriff "Gaunersprache" genannt wird. Weiter wird dann gerne erklärt, "Rotwelsch" sei "die Sprache der Bettler, Diebe und Gauner". So heißt es in der Vorrede zu Jacob Grimms Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache (1854):

> "Die bunt gemischte, doch manche deutschen Bestandteile
>   in sich haltende rotwelsche Sprache oder **die der Bettler, Diebe und Gauner** hat man vielfach und in neuer Zeit am genügendsten gesammelt."

Und auch Roland Girtler nennt sein 1998 erschienenes Buch

> Rotwelsch. Die alte Sprache der **Gauner, Dirnen und Vagabunden**.

Wobei in den *konkreten* Sammlungen solche Ausdrucksformen (es sind aus historischer Zeit verschiedene Wortlisten bekannt, die von verschiedenen Sprachforschern oder Volkskundlern gesammelt wurden) dann realiter sehr viel jiddische oder "zigeunerische" (das ist ein Zitat aus einem solchen Werk) Wörter enthalten sind, daneben aber auch slawische und verschiedene dialektale.

Es werden also Sprechgewohnheiten oder Sonderwortschätze völlig unterschiedlicher (aber stets sozial niedrig eingestufter) Bevölkerungsgruppen in einen Topf geworden. Indem man diesem Sammelsurium dann den Namen "Rotwelsch" gibt, erzeugt man beim Orientierung suchenden Leser den Eindruck, "Rotwelsch" sei eine "Sprache" in dem Sinne wie "Englisch" oder "Deutsch" eine Sprache sind.

Die "Übersetzung" des Begriffs "Rotwelsch" mit "Gaunersprache", die vielen Lesern dann ausreicht im Sinne von "Ach so, ja, jetzt verstehe ich, was Rotwelsch ist" krankt dann weiter daran, dass unklar ist, was "Gauner" eigentlich sein sollen. Die meisten Nutzer der deutschen Sprache werden zwar ein ungefähres Bild haben, was für sie ein "Gauner" wäre (z.B. ein dem Gewerbe des Betrugs nachgehender Mensch, oder vielleicht auch einfach nur ein Obdachloser), aber für eine wissenschaftliche Definition einer Sprache oder Subform einer Sprache ist diese nebulöse soziale Klassifizierung ungeeignet.

**Nachtrag**

Dieser Beitrag nimmt bewusst eine kritische Haltung ein gegenüber einer verbreiteten, leichtfertigen Verwendung des Begriffs "Rotwelsch". Er soll nicht infrage stellen, dass es möglicherweise zu bestimmten Zeiten im deutschsprachigen Raum einen Sonderwortschatz (oder mehrere Sonderwortschätze) von nicht sesshaften Mitgliedern der Gesamtbevölkerung gegeben haben kann. Die Kritik richtet sich gegen die oft allzu schnell gegebene Erklärung "Das ist ein Ausdruck aus dem Rotwelschen", wie sie bei bestimmen Wörtern gerne gegeben wird, nicht zuletzt auch in diesem schönen Forum. Hebräische, slawische und andere Ausdrücke können auch direkt von den Herkunftssprachen in bestimmte deutsche Soziolekte übernommen worden sein. So war zum Beispiel bei Bauern in Teilen Oberschwabens das Zählen auf Hebräisch noch in der ersten Hälfte des 20. Jahrhunderts bekannt und beliebt - nämlich dort, wo der Viehhandel verbreiteterweise in der Hand jüdischer Händler aus den Gemeinden der Umgebung lag. Ein Zwischenschritt über "das Rotwelsche" muss hier nicht angenommen werden.

**Literatur**

- Eine bekannte, große Sammlung ist: ***Sigmund A. Wolf***: Deutsche Gaunersprache. Wörterbuch des Rotwelschen. Bibliographisches Institut + Brockhaus, 1956. Im Vorwort sind auch die verschiedenen Vorgängersammlungen genannt, auf die sich dieses Kompendium bezieht.
- Eine beliebte frühe Quelle ist: *Actenmäßige Nachricht von einer zahlreichen Diebs-Bande, welche von einem zu Hildburghausen in gefänglicher Hafft sitzenden mitschuldigen jungen Dieb entdecket worden nebst einem Anhang aus denen wider die Anno 1745. allhier hingerichtete Gaudiebe Johann Georg Schwartzmüller und Friedrich Werner verführten Inquisitions-Actis, auch vermehrtes Verzeichniß vorgekommener Wörter von der Spitzbuben-Sprache; Ingleichen: angehängte kurtze Nachricht von der neuentdeckten Diebs-Bande in Chur-Sachsen*, von 1745. Das 56seitige Werk ist z.B. in der Universitätsbibliothek Tübingen zu finden, interessanterweise unter der Autorenbezeichnung **Schwartzmüller, Johann Georg; Werner, Friedrich**
- Noch früher verwenden **Martin Luther** und **Mathias Hüttlin** den Begriff: *Von der falschen Betler buberey Vnd hinden an ein Rotwelsch Vocabularius, daraus man die woerter, so yn diesem buechlin gebraucht, verstehen kan*, publiziert 1528 in Wittenberg ["Wittemberg"]. 24 Seiten.
- Eine modernere Darstellung findet man vom Soziologen ***Roland Girtler***: Rotwelsch. Die alte Sprache der Gauner, Dirnen und Vagabunden. Wien, Köln, Weimar (Böhlau-Verlag) 1998, und spätere Neuauflagen. - Hier wird die Behauptung vertreten, dass das "Rotwelsche" bei "Stadtstreichern, Ganoven und Dirnen" auch heute in Gebrauch sei. Was vielleicht ein bisschen weit hergeholt ist, außer man bezeichnet eben jede deutsche Sprachform sozialer Randgruppen als "Rotwelsch". Interessant ist, dass der Autor sich unter anderem auf seine Kontakte und Studienbesuche in der Wiener Rotlichtszene stützt. Das Buch ist amüsant, aber ich finde es extrem unwissenschaftlich. Es fehlt jegliche Reflektion über den Begriff "Rotwelsch" und seinen realweltlichen Referenzpunkt. Vielmehr wird wie so oft einfach hingenommen, dass es ein "Rotwelsch" gebe, und dann werden mehr oder weniger belegbare Geschichten darumherumformuliert. Gleichwohl setzt der Autor das Wort "Rotwelsch" durchweg in Gänsefüßchen, als wolle er sich heimlich dann doch davon distanzieren.

Comment: Deine Antwort liest sich so, als ob es unter den mittelalterlichen und späteren Gaunerbanden (die es tatsächlich gegeben hat - soziale Randgruppen sind leider keine "Erfindung") so etwas wie eine **verbindende** Geheimsprache gar nicht gegeben hätte. Ich denke, das kann man so nicht sagen. Immerhin war diese "Sondersprache" so breit gestreut, dass sie Einzug in die allgemeine Umgangssprache und sogar in die Standardsprache genommen hat. Das Besondere ist ja gerade, dass es eben **nicht** die "verschiedensten Randgruppen" gesprochen haben sondern die "organisierte Kriminalität" im Mittelalters.

Comment: @Takkat  Wieso glaubst du, es liege hier eine "Geheimsprache" vor? Ich weiß, es wird oft so behauptet. Aber das ist vermutlich nur wieder die Außensicht. Nur weil mir Wörter nicht bekannt sind, ist es nicht unbedingt eine Geheimsprache, sonst wäre Japanisch für mich auch eine Geheimsprache. Ich glaube nicht, dass die Träger der hier diskutierten Sprachformen diese eigens geschaffen haben, um von anderen *nicht verstanden* zu werden. Eher haben sie natürlichweise unter sich so gesprochen. Der Eindruck des "Geheimen" ist eine Interpretation der z.B. Stadtbürger, die den Wortschatz nicht kannten.

Comment: @Takkat   Bei der Verwendung des Begriffs "organisierte Kriminalität" wäre ich ebenfalls vorsichtig. Ich würde "organisierte Kriminalität" eher verwenden für auf sehr hohem Niveau organisierte illegale Aktivitäten, und das schließt für mich idealtypisch ein, dass Personen aus den höheren Schichten der Gesellschaft (reiche Leute und Amtsinhaber) eingebunden sind. Eine Gruppe von Obdachlosen, die sich im Wald verstecken und nachts in Bauernstuben einbrechen, um Wurst und Schinken zu stehlen, würde ich nicht als "organisierte Kriminalität" bezeichnen.

Comment: Es gab damals durchaus eine bandenartig organisierte Kleinkriminalität die natürlich nicht mit der heutigen organisierten Kriminaltät vergleichbar ist. Die Sprachwissenschaftler (ich bin keiner!) sind sich einig, dass sich in diesen Banden ein eigener Jargon, eine eigene Sondersprache entwickelt hat, mit dem Ziel 1. Zusammengehörigkeit zu vermitteln und 2. von den Bürgerlichen nicht belauscht werden zu können. Deine "Gruppe von Odachlosen, die sich im Wald verstecken" ist eine romantische Verklärung.

Comment: @Takkat Meine "Gruppe von Obdachlosen, die sich im Wald verstecken" war eine bewusste (auch leicht ironische) Vereinfachung zum Behufe der Verdeutlichung des Problems mit dem Begriff "organisierte Kriminalität" bei der Anwendung auf soziale Strukturen der Vormoderne.

Comment: @Takkat   - Bezüglich der (historischen) Existenz einer "rotwelschen" Sprache als Gemein- und Geheimsprache bestimmter sozialer Gruppen im deutschsprachigen Raum des z.B. 15. bis 19. Jahrhunderts wäre ich nach wie vor sehr vorsichtig. "Sprachwissenschaftler sind sich einig" ist kein Argument. Welche Sprachwissenschaftler? Gestützt auf welche Argument und welche Vorgängerforschung? 40 Prozent der US-Amerikaner sind sich einig, dass die Erde 6000 Jahre alt ist. Einig mögen sie sich sein, aber recht haben sie deswegen noch nicht.

Comment: Deine Abhandlung hat sicher ihre Berechtigung. Leider finden wir aber für die hier enthaltenen kritischen Behauptungen keine wissenschaftliche Quelle, und du führst auch keine an. Im Gegenteil, die von dir in der weiterführenden Literatur aufgeführten Autoren haben eben kein Problem mit dem Begriff *Rotwelsch*.  Ich meine also, dass es sich hier weitestgehend um deine eigene, persönliche Meinung handelt. Wir begrüßen das hier, aber du solltest die Teile deiner Antwort, bei denen es sich um deine persönliche Meinung handelt, besser als solche kennzeichnen.

Comment: Ich glaube deine Antwort (speziell die Aussage "Es gibt kein gemeinsames Rotwelsch") lässt den sozialpsychologischen Aspekt, dass Menschen "einer bestimmten Herde" zugehören *wollen*, außer acht. Genausogut könntest du auch sagen "es gibt keine Jugendsprache" - Die es aber definitiv gibt.

Comment: Was mich sehr wundert: *wo* soll denn Rotwelsch verbreitet gewesen sein? Vagabunden über den gesamten deutschsprachigen Raum verteilt und da dann dieser *eine* Sonderwortschatz? (Heisst: ich stimme der artifiziellen Vergesellschaftungsthese hier zu und vermute zig Arten von Rotwelsch) Würde mich allerdings sehr freuen dazu noch ein paar Belegstellen mehr zu lesen. Vielleicht [hülffts.](http://home.balcab.ch/venanz.nobel/ausstellung/Rotwelsch.htm)

Comment: @LangLangC Du scheinst die Haupteigenschaft von *Vagabunden* zu vergessen - Die sassen ja nicht an einem Platz rum und haben isoliert ihre eigene Version des Rotwelschen gepflegt. Viele dieser Leute waren im ganzen deutschsprachigen Raum (und darüberhinaus) unterwegs und hinterliessen überall ihre sprachlichen Spuren.

Comment: @tofro Was ich sofort eingestehe: meine Vorstellung von Anzahl und Reichweite der Vagabundenwanderschaften kann sehr daneben sein. Wenn ich aber lese wie Bayern und Friesen sich per Dialekt nicht gut verständigen konnten, dann wundert's mich, wie ein Schwabenzimmermann mit einem Ostpreußenbettler zurechtgekommen sein soll. Wie weit reicht die gegenseitige Verständlichkeit des einen Soziolekts *Rotwelsch*? Ich vermute noch immer, dass eine grobe Sozialzuschreibung die Linguistik in eine "Sonstige"-Schublade zu zwängen versucht hat. Der Begriff täuscht da Homogenität vor, wo Unordnung herrscht.

Comment: Ich glaube, deine Vorstellung ist da zu kleinräumig. Zigeuner reisen schon seit Jahrhunderten einmal im Jahr von Osteuropa nach Saintes-Maries-de-la-Mer, Bauarbeiter aus Italien haben die großen Alpentunnel gebaut und im Mittelalter fuhren Flößer aus dem Schwarzwald Baumstämme bis nach Rotterdam oder von Ulm ans Schwarze Meer. Und natürlich haben die sich alle unterwegs getroffen. Wandernde Bauarbeiter reisten durch Deutschland und bauten große Kirchen. Es ist nachgewiesen, dass Handwerker, die das Ulmer Münster gebaut haben, auch am Straßburger Münster und am Dom in Prag mitgebaut haben.

Comment: @tofro  Die Mobilität nicht unerheblicher Bevölkerungsteile (Handwerker, große und kleine Händler, Söldner, Jahrmarktleute, Sexarbeiterinnen, Zigeuner, Kinder und Männer aus Gebirgsdörfern, die ins Flachland zur Arbeit geschickt werden, etc. etc.) über Jahrhunderte sehe ich durchaus. Dass sich bei diesen im Kontakt untereinander schnell Mischlexik(en) oder Mischsprache(n) gebildet hat/haben, ist nachvollziehbar. Meine Frage ist aber, wie **homogen** (= allen hier unterstellten Beteiligten verständlich) diese war und ob man sie darum in *eine* Schachtel mit Namen "Rotwelsch" stecken darf.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann Gegenfrage: Wie **homogen** muss eine Sprache sein (z.B. zwischen Ostfriesland und Bern), damit man sie in **eine** Schachtel mit Namen "Deutsch" stecken darf?

Comment: @tofro   Gute Frage. Gute Antwort: Das verbindende Element der Sprachvarietäten zwischen Bern und Leer ist die gemeinsame Schriftlichkeit, wie sie insbesondere im Schulbuch auftritt, und in der Folge dann auch in amtlichem Schriftverkehr und Rechtssprache, im wirtschaftlichen Schriftverkehr, in den Massenmedien sowie in Wissenschaft und Belletristik. - Bulgarisch und Makedonisch sind sich deutlich ähnlicher als Norddeutsch und Süddeutsch, aber sie werden als getrennte Sprachen geführt, weil es getrennte Schulbücher etc. gibt.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Dannisjagut - Denn zwischen Rotwelsch Nord und Rotwelsch Süd gibt es keine getrennten Schulbücher.

Answer (score 2):

Rotwelsch, gebildet aus *Rot* (Rotwelsch: Landstreicher, oder *rot* für krank/schlecht) und *welsch* als landläufige Bezeichnung für alles Fremde, ist die Bezeichnung für eine Unterform der deutschen Sprache, die von sozialen (Rand-)gruppen verwendet wurde, die aus den verschiedensten Gründen dauerhaft auf der Landstrasse unterwegs waren.

Rotwelsch gilt nicht als eine eigenständige Sprache, denn sie verwendet Grammatik und Wortbildungsformen der deutschen Sprache. Sie unterscheidet sich vom Deutschen durch eine Menge von Vokabeln, die aus Vokabularien fremder Sprachen übernommen wurden, die eben auf der Landstrasse zu hören waren (Die Herkunftsgruppen in Klammern sind mögliche Beispiele):

- Jiddisch (fahrende jüdische Händler)
- Romanes (Zigeuner, fahrendes Volk, teilweise fahrende Kleinhandwerker wie Scherenschleifer und Kesselflicker)
- Niederländisch (Landsknechte)
- Französisch (Soldaten)
- Italienisch (Händler und Schausteller)
- Latein (fahrende Schüler und Studenten)

Gesprochen und verstanden wurde diese "Sprache" auch von Handwerksburschen auf der Walz und vielen anderen, "fahrenden" Bevölkerungsgruppen (mit durchaus unterschiedlichem sozialen Status, sieht man einmal davon ab, dass für die ansässige Bevölkerung erstmal jeder, der auf der Landstrasse unterwegs war, dubios erscheinen musste).

Man darf sich die Entstehung dieser "Sprache" so vorstellen, dass sie sich zuerst hauptsächlich als gemeinsames Identifikationsmerkmal einer sozialen Gruppe (vgl. heutige Jugendsprache(n)) entstand, und wegen ihres speziellen Wortschatzes natürlich auch dazu geeignet war, Personen mit "dunklen Absichten" als "Geheimsprache" zu dienen, die Leuten außerhalb dieser sozialen Gruppe größtenteils unverständlich war - Die Obrigkeit, und damit auch die Literatur, hat natürlich vorrangig auf Letzteres fokussiert, weswegen z.B. für die Polizei eigens Wörterbücher dieser "Gaunersprache" entstanden sind. Deswegen sollte man sich nicht unbedingt vorstellen, dass jeder, der diesen speziellen Wortschatz verwendet hat, auch gleichzeitig ein Gauner war - Natürlich ist es so, dass man, wenn man sich abends auf der Strasse einem Lagerfeuer genähert hat, an dem schon "Fahrende" saßen, man sich sehr viel schneller aufgenommen sah, wenn man sich schon durch die Sprache als einen der Ihren eingeführt hat.

Comment: [Rot](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=BMZ&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=BR01545#XBR01545) = ehemals wie Rost = verrottet, verdorben, schlecht. [Welsch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=BMZ&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=BR01545#XBR01545) = romanisch, französisch, italienisch, oder halt umgangssprachlich auch für *fremde Sprache*

Comment: @Takkat Zu *Rot* scheint es wohl unterschiedliche Meinungen zu geben. Kann auch einfach *krank* heißen (siehe *Rotlauf*), im Rotwelschen selbst heißt *rot* wohl tatsächlich Gauner oder Landstreicher.

Comment: Ja genau. Rot scheint eine gleiche Etymologie wie das Englische *rotten* zu haben, deshalb auch mein Link im obigen Kommentar auf ein mittelhochdeutsches Wörterbuch. Viele Bezeichnungen des Rotwelsch sollen nämlich noch aus dem Mittelhochdeutsch kommen.

Comment: Die direkt mhd. Herkunft von rotwelschen Vokabeln dürfte sehr schwer zu beweisen sein - weil eben Deutsch als Basis auch viele (oh Wunder!) ursprünglich mittelhochdeutsche Vokabeln hat. (Soll heißen: Viele mhd-Vokabeln könnten auch aus dem archaischen Deutsch übernommen und dort inzwischen ausgestorben sein)

Comment: Ich glaube, so ist es gemeint: viele Vokabeln sind nahezu unverändert aus dem mnhd. tradiert.

Answer (score 1):

Rotwelsch nennt man in der Sprachwissenschaft die im Mittelalter entstandene "frühere Geheimsprache asozialer, meist vagabundierender Personen und Gruppen, die auch zur Verschleierung krimineller Inhalte diente und heute nur noch in einzelnen Ausdrücken Verwendung findet". <sup>[[1]](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Rotwelsch)</sup>

Sprache wurde schon immer "von unten" gemacht, d.h. die Sprache der unteren sozialen Schicht beeinflusst ständig stark die Hochsprache. Deswegen haben sich viele Begriffe und Phrasen (teilweise nur regional) in die allgemeine Umgangssprache und einige sogar in die Standardsprache "hochgearbeitet".<sup>[[2]](http://www.detlev-mahnert.de/rotwelsch.html)</sup>

*Rot* kommt entweder von "Rotte" (Bande) oder mittelniederländisch rot (faul/schmutzig). *Welsch* hat die Bedeutung "fremdartig". <sup>[[3]](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotwelsch)</sup>

---

Rotwelsch is called in the linguistics an in the mediaeval originated, "former secret language of antisocial, mostly vagabonding persons and groups, which also served to disguise criminal content, and is now only in individual terms use".

Language has always been made "from the bottom", i. the language of the lower social class is strongly influencing the high-level language. Therefore, many terms and phrases (sometimes only regional) in the general colloquial language and some even in the standard language "worked up".

Red comes either from "Rotte" (gang) or middle Dutch rot (lazy / dirty). Welsch has the meaning "alien".