# Wortherkunft: Wieso und seit wann ist ein Voyeur ein "Spanner"

Tags: meaning, etymology

Das [Wortschatzlexikon](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl_2011&word=Spanner) beschreibt den *Spanner* als zugehörig zum

> Sachgebiet: Maschinenbau, Spezielle Zoologie, Verpackungstechnik

Nennt dann aber unter den Verwendungsbeispielen mit

> Einige Zeit später tauchte der Spanner in einem benachbarten Anwesen wieder auf.

Die Bedeutung von *Spanner* als Voyeur.

Dies ist laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Spanner) die häufigste, gemäß [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Spanner) und DWDS nur die [dritthäufigste](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Spanner) Bedeutung für Spanner.

Die Suche nach der [Etymologie führt über das Verb *spannen* in verwirrend urgermanische Gefilde](https://www.dwds.de/wb/spannen):

> spannen Vb. ‘etw. straff (an)ziehen, dehnen’, intransitiv ‘zu eng, zu straff sein’ (besonders von der Kleidung), reflexiv ‘straff werden’. Das ursprünglich stark flektierende (reduplizierende) Verb ahd. spannan ‘fesseln, spannen’ (9. Jh.), mhd. spannen ‘dehnen, straff anziehen’, intransitiv ‘sich dehnen, gespannt sein’, asächs. spannan, mnd. mnl. nl. spannen, afries. spanna, aengl. spannan ‘spannen, festbinden, anfügen’ (germ. *spannan) und das schwach flektierende zugehörige Kausativum mhd. mnd. spennen ‘spannen, dehnen’, anord. spenna ‘spannen, festbinden, fügen’, schwed. spänna ‘spannen, schnallen’ (germ. *spannijan) stehen mit Gemination neben dem (in ↗abspenstig, s. d., resthaft erhaltenen) stark flektierenden Verb ahd. spanan (9. Jh.), mhd. spanen ‘locken, reizen, antreiben’, asächs. aengl. spanan, afries. spana (germ. *spanan) sowie der unter ↗Spange (s. d.) abgehandelten Gutturalerweiterung. Diese ein präsensbildendes n aufweisenden Verben lassen sich außergerm. mit griech. spā́n (σπᾶν) ‘ziehen, zerren, reißen, verrenken’, spasmós (σπασμός) ‘das Ziehen, Zuckung, Krampf’, air. sēim ‘winzig, mager’, sēime ‘Dünne’ vergleichen, so daß eine Wurzel ie. *sp(h)ē(i)- ‘ziehen, spannen’ möglich ist. Vielleicht ist daran auch ie. *(s)pen(d)- (s. ↗spinnen) anzuschließen. Grundlage der Bedeutung von spannen ist wohl das Straffziehen der Bogensehne. spannend Part.adj. ‘das Interesse erregend’ (19. Jh.). gespannt Part.adj. ‘interessiert, neugierig, in ungeduldiger Erwartung begriffen’, übertragen ‘konfliktgeladen, gereizt, unharmonisch’ (18. Jh.). angespannt Part.adj. ‘angestrengt, aufmerksam, kompliziert, schwierig’ (18. Jh.). abgespannt Part.adj. ‘erschlafft, ermüdet’ (18. Jh.). überspannt Part.adj. ‘übertrieben, unrealistisch, wirklichkeitsfremd’ (18. Jh.). einspannen Vb. ‘(Zugtiere) vor den Wagen spannen’, übertragen ‘für bestimmte Zwecke einsetzen’, mhd. īnspannen ‘umschließen, fesseln’. ausspannen Vb. ‘ausdehnen, ausstrecken, das Zaumzeug abnehmen, sich ausruhen’ (15. Jh.). vorspannen Vb. ‘Zugtiere anschirren, etw. straff anziehend ausbreiten’ (16. Jh.); Vorspann m. ‘dem Hauptgespann vorangespannte Zugtiere’ (17. Jh.), modern ‘einem Film oder Text (als Einleitung) Vorangestelltes’. Spann m. ‘oberer Teil des Fußes vom Schienbeinansatz bis zu den Zehen, Gespann’ (18. Jh.), älter (16. Jh.) vereinzelt auch für Spanne f. Maßbezeichnung für die Entfernung zwischen den Spitzen von ausgestrecktem Daumen und Zeigefinger bzw. kleinem Finger, ahd. spanna (9. Jh.), mhd. mnd. mnl. spanne ‘Breite der ausgebreiteten Hand’ (germ. *spannō); vgl. spannenlang, mhd. spannelanc. Später (18. Jh.) auch übertragen für die Dauer einer Zeit eine (kurze) Spanne Zeit. Spannung f. ‘Tätigkeit des Spannens, Gespanntsein’ (17. Jh.), ‘Zustand gestörter Harmonie’ (18. Jh.), ‘psychischer Zustand der Erwartung und angestrengter Aufmerksamkeit’ (19. Jh.), in der Elektrotechnik Kurzwort für Stromspannung (19. Jh.). Spannkraft f. ‘Elastizität’, übertragen ‘Elan, Energie, Leistungsfähigkeit’ (18. Jh.).

Nur ist von *Spanner* bei Jacob [Grimm im Wörterbuch gar nicht die Rede als Beobachter](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/Spanner), wohl aber in der [jüngeren Gegenwartssprache](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wdg/Spanner):

> III. salopp jmd., der bei einer verbotenen, ungesetzlichen Sache Wache steht:
>
> > In der stillen, geruhig-anständigen Straße trieben Schlepper und
> >     Spanner ihr Unwesen, sie holten das Publikum zusammen ...
> >     Provinzonkels, angesäuselte Herren

Das ist also immer noch nicht der Voyeur. Der jüngsten Erklärung hier zu Folge ist ein *Spanner* jemand der "Schmiere steht".

Einige ältere, ähnliche Bedeutungen scheinen für das Wort *spannen* belegt zu sein:

> *in obscöner übertragung:* der gute geselle der noch nicht entschlaffen was, die frawe mit frölichem verporgem herczen enpfinge und on icht anders gesprochen zu dreien malen sein armprust spannet und abschosse. Steinhöwel decam. 571, 12 Keller. als technisch geprägter ausdruck dann auch auf jüngere arten von schuszwaffen übertragen: spannen,
>
> fast sprichwörtlicher vergleich, von einem finstern, argwöhnischen, lauernden menschen (vgl. unten unter B den scheinbar intransitiven gebrauch des wortes):
>   ja der könig lacht fürwahr ganz selten.
>   was man jhm sagt, so freut jhn nichtsen,
>   sicht stets ausz wie ein gespante püchsen.
>   Ayrer 1617 Keller (schöne Melusine).
>
> so auch von den sinnen des menschen, das auge, den blick spannen: mit gespannten augen blickte tante Frieder nach dem verblichenen kunstwerke. Storm 3, 175;
>   so unverwandt 
>   und gierig hielten stets Venetiens blonde söhne 
>   die augen nur auf sie gespannt. 
>   Wieland Pervonte 3, 366;
>
> von lebewesen auf etwas spannen, angestrengt auf etwas achten, nach einem gegenstande ausblicken, verlangen. wendungen wie auf einen spannen mit dem bogen, intendere arcum in aliquem Dentzler 2, 267b erklären den gebrauch.
>   a) auf etwas spannen, etwas verlangend beobachten. Tübinger studentenausdruck; von auf den fang ausgehenden freudenmädchen. Avé-Lallemant 4, 609; von thieren: die katz spannet auf eine maus, der fuchs spannet auf die hüner. Kramer dict. 2, 846c; von der eule: erstlich waren meine haare in dritthalb jahren weder auff griechisch, teutsch noch frantzösisch abgeschnitten, gekampelt, noch gekräuselt oder gebüfft worden, sondern sie stunden in ihrer natürlichen verwirrung ... so zierlich auff meinem kopff, dasz ich darunter herfür sahe mit meinem bleichgelben angesicht wie eine schleyereule, die knappen will oder sonst auf eine maus spannet. Simpl. 1, 65, 16 Kurz; übertragen von einem kraut, dessen stengel nach unten strebt, auf dem erdboden kinkriecht: daʒ kraut (pörzelkraut) spannet mit seinem stengel auf die erd. Megenberg 416, 14; unsinnlicher gewandt: sie meynens gut mit ihm (dem taubstummen, Marc. 7, 32), und er läszt sich mitnehmen. er wehrt sich wenigstens nicht, sondern spannet eben in seinem gemüth darauf, was es werden wolle. Ph. Burk evangelienpostille (1774) 2, 122; vgl. mhd.:
>   in mîner âbentzît ich bin 
>   unt trage doch jungen liutengar junclîchen morgen schîn: 
>   ich lege mich ûf mînen armunt spanne doch nâch êren wol. 
>   Reinmar v. Zweter 180, 3 Roethe;
>
> mîn sin der spannet unde dent
>   dar ûf mit hôhem flîʒe,
>   daʒ ich vil tage verslîʒe
>   ob einem tiefen buoche.
>   Konrad v. Würzburg troj. krieg 216.
>
> b) seine aufmerksamkeit auf etwas richten, aufachten, lauschen, bemerken u.s.w.: ein jeder spannte, als er anfing zu erzählen; so sehr ich auch spannte, konnte ich doch nichts hören; ich wendete das gesicht nach der seite, woher das geräusch kam, und spannte. Campe; auch der hund spannt. ebenda; nach a in der bedeutung hinübergehend:
>   wenn der fischer 's netz auswirft,
>   die fischlein aufzufangen,
>   spannt er still und hoffnungsvoll,
>   viel beute zu erlangen.
>   Göthe 11, 99 (fischerin);
>
> [Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob Grimm und Wilhelm Grimm auf CD-ROM und im Internet](http://dwb.uni-trier.de/de) Eintrag: [spannen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS32615#XGS32615)

**Was ist nun also die Geschichte dieses Wortes, in dieser Verwendung als Voyeur? Wo kommt es her? Wie kam es zu dieser Bedeutung? Seit wann hat es auch diese Bedeutung?**

---

Update: Diesen nun zu dieser Frage neu hinzugefügten, zahlreichen Bedeutungsvarianten des Verbs *spannen* nach müsste es den *Spanner* also schon seit sehr langer Zeit geben. Unklar bleibt aber weiterhin, seit wann "Der ist ja ein Spanner" diese relativ klare, negativ besetzte, Bedeutungsverengung auf einen optisch stimulierten, meist unerwünschten Perversling erhalten hat.

Comment: Interessant in dem Zusammenhang vielleicht auch: »Das hab ich gespannt« bedeutet in der bairischen Umgangssprache »Das habe ich verstanden«.

Answer (score 10):

Grimms Wörterbuch kennt den Begriff zwar nicht unter *Spanner* sondern unter

> **Spannerei:** f., in der gaunersprache: aussicht, ausblick in die landschaft.

Wobei es nicht vorschreibt, dass es in der Landschaft irgendwas bestimmtes zu sehen gäbe. Irgendeine Art von sexueller Anspannung scheint also nicht damit verbunden zu sein, sondern eher das Schauen (Ausschau halten, nach z.B dem Polizist) an sich.

... und schon wieder Gaunersprache:

> **Spannmichel**, m. auge, in der gaunersprache;

Wenn ein *Spanner* also jemand ist, der nur kuckt, dann ist es ja immerhin die direkte Übersetzung von *Voyeur*.

Warum die Herren Grimm den *Spanner* selbst nicht in ihr Wörterbuch aufgenommen haben, erschließt sich mir nicht, ich denke es ist mit diesen beiden Einträgen naheliegend, dass es diesen Begriff damals schon gegeben haben muss.

Answer (score 5):

### ***Spannen* im Mittelhochdeutschen: »freudig erregt sein«**

Im "Herkunftswörterbuch" von Duden (Ausgabe von 2014) findet sich zwar kein eigener Eintrag zu "Spanner", jedoch findet man unter ***spannen*** einige Zeilen, die hier relevant zu sein scheinen:

> Die häufige übertragene Verwendung von *spannen* geht ursprünglich vom Bild des gespannten Jagdbogens aus; schon mhd. *spannen* bedeutete auch »voller Verlangen sein; freudig erregt sein«.

Direkt im Anschluss wird noch weiter ausgeführt:

> Heute liegt eher die Vorstellung der Stahlfeder oder der gespannten Muskeln zugrunde, besonders im adjektivischen Gebrauch der Partizipien **spannend** »erregend« und **gespannt** »erwartungsvoll« (seit dem 19. Jh.); man beachte auch **angespannt** »aufmerksam« [...]

(Hervorhebungen wie im Original)

### ***Spannen* und *Spanner* laut 'Wörterbuch des Rotwelschen"**

Der Eintrag *spannen* im "Wörterbuch des Rotwelschen" von S. A. Wolf (1956) nennt als Grundbedeutung:

> sehen, beobachten, aufpassen

(es folgen etliche zahlenkodierte Fundstellen aus den Jahren 1687 bis 1956).

Für ***Spanner*** heißt es im selben Eintrag weiter unten:

> Aufpasser, Wächter, Detektiv, Vigilant

Dazu werden auch noch die Wörter *Spannjunge* und *Spann-Nase* aufgeführt.

Von einer sexuellen Konnotierung von *Spanner* ist in diesem Wörterbucheintrag nicht die Rede. Allerdings würde ich der prüden Zeit (Mitte der 1950er) zutrauen, dass solche Bedeutungen in Buchpublikationen aus falsch verstandenem Anstand möglicherweise auch einfach ausgelassen wurden.

Zur grundsätzlich gebotenen Vorsicht, unerklärlichen Wörtern im Deutschen einfach eine Herkunft "aus dem Rotwelschen" zuzuschreiben, siehe die Diskussion in diesem Forum unter [Was ist Rotwelsch? What is "Rotwelsch"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46700/was-ist-rotwelsch-what-is-rotwelsch).

**Literatur**

Siegmund A. Wolf: Wörterbuch des Rotwelschen. Deutsche Gaunersprache. Mannheim, Bibliographisches Institut, 1956.

Comment: Ich bezweifle ein bßchen, dass der Schmieresteher beim Bruch "freudig erregt" Ausschau nach den Wachtmeistern gehalten hat. Diese Bedeutung geht eher in die Richtung "da bin ich aber gespannt, was ich zu Weihnachten kriege", die mit dem *Spanner* wohl wenig zu tun haben dürfte

Comment: @tofro  Es ging bei der Eingangsfrage um den **Spanner als Voyeur**. Da passt "freudig erregt" doch wie der Faust aufs Gretchen. Der Umweg über den Schmierensteher aus einer sogenannten Gaunersprache muss man - legt jedenfalls Dudens Herkunftswörterbuch nahe - vielleicht gar nicht nehmen.

Comment: Laut dem Grimm scheint der "Umweg" zwingend.

Comment: @tofro  Grimm in Ehren, aber haben die Gebrüder die Wahrheit gebucht? Wenn Prof. Jörg Riecke (Hg. des Herkunftswörterbuchs) "spannen = freudig erregt sein" schon im Mittelhochdeutschen findet, könnte der Umweg über die Bedeutung "Schmierestehen" doch in der Tat unnötig sein? Siehe auch die in der Eingangsfrage zitierten Funde: "a) auf etwas spannen, etwas verlangend beobachten. Tübinger studentenausdruck; von auf den fang ausgehenden freudenmädchen. Avé-Lallemant 4, 609; von thieren: die katz spannet auf eine maus, der fuchs spannet auf die hüner. Kramer dict. 2, 846c;"

Comment: Muss *Rotwelsch* seit der neulich geführten Debatte immer in Anführungszeichen gesetzt werden? Da könnte man auch *Mittelhochdeutsch* in Anführungszeichen setzen. ;-)

Comment: @Philipp  Ich will es mir mal 'überlegen'. [Später:] Ah! Ich habe einen Ausweg gefunden. Ich schreibe "Spanner im 'Wörterbuch des Rotwelschen'. Damit umgehen wir das Problem.

Answer (score 1):

Da in den bisherigen Antworten nicht viel zum "seit wann?" gesagt wurde: In Falladas Roman *Wolf unter Wölfen* (geschrieben 1937, spielt 1923) scheint *Spanner* noch ein Wort der Gaunersprache zu sein, mit der in Wolfs *Wörterbuch des Rotwelschen* angegebenen Bedeutung *Aufpasser, Wächter*.

> Was ist ein Spanner, Pagel? fragte Studmann sanft.
>
> Ein Spanner ist jemand, erklärte Pagel bereitwillig, der spannt, ob die Schupo kommt und ob überhaupt die Luft rein ist. Und der die Haustür eben schnell abschloß, das war der Schlepper, der schleppt die Gäste rauf... ([Quelle](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/-10054/8))

In einer Rezension in der *Zeit* aus dem Jahr 1966 ist dem Autor das Wort *Spanner* gänzlich unbekannt:

> Nur eins hätte ich von Heinrich Böll gern gewißt [sic]: Was ist ein „Spanner“? Ich hatte schon Schwierigkeiten, den englischen Titel „The Scarperer“ zu verstehen [...] ([Quelle](https://www.zeit.de/1966/49/poet-und-saeufer/seite-2))

(Im Englischen heißt *to scarper* eigentlich *wegrennen*, aber in dem Roman scheint es um jemanden zu gehen, der Häftlingen zur Flucht verhilft. Jedenfalls ein Gauner, kein Voyeur.)

Das ist alles leider nur negative Evidenz, die aber darauf hindeutet, daß die Bedeutung *Voyeur* sehr jung ist.

Answer (score 0):

Könnte gut mit *spy*, *Spion* verwandt sein, jemand der guckt,  vgl. *spec-*.

*spectre* heißt auch Geist, ist also etwas unheimliches.

Im Rotwelschen ließen sich einige Wortspiele vermuten:

Im Sinne von *Speck*, *Fett*, würde das evtl. auch "Schmiere stehen" erklären, das mich schon länger wurmte.

Mit En. *spanner* wird jemand bezeichnet, der die Pferde flott macht, das Geschirr einspannt, wenn ich mich richtig erinnere. Das bildet vllt. einen weiteren Zusammenhang hinsichtlich der Flucht (im Pferdewagen?).

Im Sinne von *spinnen* ist es vllt. jemand der beim Einbruch Deckung bietet (die Decke webt? wohl kaum), und im Sinne von *spin* ein krummes Ding *dreht*.

Edit: *Spanne* selbst wird auf en.wt/[Spanne](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Spanne) über *Hand-Spanne" erklärt, was unglaublich viel Sinn ergeben würde, insoweit Ur-Indo-Germanisch *penkwos "5" auf die volle Hand zurückgeführt werden kann (vgl. Lt. *pungo*), und s-mobile gesondert zu betrachten wäre (also etwa *(s)pen-?); Zudem wird *Hand* selbst auch gelegentlich dazugerechnet.

Comment: "Im Sinne von Speck, Fett, würde das evtl. auch "Schmiere stehen" erklären, das mich schon länger wurmte."
Aber die Schmiere hat doch nix mit Fett zu tun, sondern kommt vom jiddischen "shmira" (Wache). Auch die sonstigen Erklärungen klingen etwas sehr weit hergeholt...

Comment: Jiddisch, Rotwelsch, merkste selber, wa?

Comment: Es hat trotzdem nix mit "Speck, Fett" zu tun, wa?

Comment: @mic ja na mag sein, womit denn dann, Hebräisch?

Comment: Hebr. *shamar* bedeutet "to keep, protect" aber auch "yeast", was wohl daher kommen dürfte, dass immer etwas Teig für den nächsten Ansatz aufgehoben wird (cp *leaven*; *Hefe, heben*). Wenn ich mich recht erinnere, hat *Semmel* semitische Bekannte. Wäre nicht abwegig anzunehmen, der "Schmarrn" komme auch daher; *16 JH zu "schmer, schmieren"* . Zu fettigem Essen ist es dann nicht weit. Speck wird auch haltbar gemacht und aufgehoben. "Schmier" kann angeblich auch für Polizei stehen, vgl. "bacon", dessen Herkunft ungewiss ist, vermutlich im Sinne *Rückenfett*. "I got your back".

Comment: Ob *schmier-* auch daher kommt weiß ich nicht, jedoch ist Jiddisch *shmir* "spread" zu finden, sowie eine IE Rekonstruktion für "schmieren" mit relativ wenigen (laut Wiktionary) Verwandten, also unsicheren alters, zu einer Wurzel \*smer-, über die ich ob des roten wikilinks nichts genaueres weiß. Erinnert etwas an *Margarine*, aus dem Persischen aus der Bedeutung "pearl" entlehnt, wohl wegen der Tröpfchen in der Emulsion, was nicht ganz überzeugt. Perlen vor die Säue ...